# Why do class variables in Javascript disappear when trying to call them multiple times or assigning them to local variables?

Tags: javascript, variables, canvas, html5-canvas, variable-assignment

```
var width = 10;
var data = image.data;
var height = 10;

for ( var x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {

  for ( var y = 0; y < height; y++ )

    var index = 4 * (y * height +  x); // 0

    var local_variable = ArbitraryClassInstance.getBrightness(x, y); // 0

    data[ index ] = ArbitraryClassInstance.getBrightness(x, y); // 0 for both index/call
    data[ index + 1 ] = ArbitraryClassInstance.getBrightness(x, y); // 0 for both index/call

  }

}

context.putImageData(image, 0, 0);
```

Both index and local_variable are equalled to zero when I execute the code. Image is a javascript image object, data is the image data, and width and height are the dimensions of the image. The class returns brightness.

Comment: whats worng with them being zero? you mean they don't increment with the loops?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I didn't close my curly brackets. A warning to all.

Chrome/Firefox degrade gracefully and DON'T THROW AN ERROR! You will not believe how long I was chasing this bug down.

Check your syntax - javascript throws errors like pointers in C (it doesn't).

Comment: You mean you didn't open it, after the second for loop? That's no error, as in C. My favorite Browser (Opera) does throw exceptions for such cases. You might want to use a JS debugger in the future? They are great to hunt down such problems.